# Filtering AWS SNS messages by attribute value but only if attribute is present

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I would like to know how I can create a filtering policy for AWS SNS subscription that would check a message attribute value but only if that attribute is present. By default if I check an attribute value but attribute is not present message is ignored e.g:

```
"customer_interests": ["paintball"]
```

I also found this for attribute presence checking:

```
"customer_interests": [{"exists": true}]
```

But I'm not sure how to combine this two checks into a single policy.

I've tried the obvious thing:

```
{
   "customer_interests": [{"exists": false}, "paintball"]
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried your "obvious thing" and it worked for me. My tests were 1. customer_interests = "paintball" (received) 2. customer_interests = "boxe" (not) 3. name = "test", no other attrs (received)

Comment: @AlbertoAnderickJr Strange I've tried it multiple times without any luck... Will give it another shot probably.

Comment: @Pavlo I am facing the same problem as you, exists: false is not matching a message with no attributes. Did you manage to find success?

Comment: @Justin To be honest I didn't check the answer below but I had my hopes that it will work. I just didn't need this up til now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried the following thing ( your obvious thing )  and it worked for me, i didn't have to even wait for 15 minutes (clearly eventual consistency is not the issue )

Used the following policy

```
{
  "customer_interests": [
    {
      "exists": false
    },
    "paintball"
  ]
}
```

- Created a sns topic with email-based subscription
- added filter policy to subscriber

tried with three use case

Case 1

- message hello
- attribute type string
- atrribute name customer_interests
- atrribute value paintball
- status recieved

Case 3

- message hello
- attribute type string
- atrribute name customer_interests
- atrribute value xyz
- status not recieved

Case 3

- message hello
- attribute type string
- atrribute name jatin
- atrribute value test
- status recieved

Comment: Please note that this only works if any message attribute is present. From the documentation: "Note: "exists": false only matches if at least one attribute is present. An empty set of attributes results in the filter not matching."

Answer (score 0):

You apply OR logic in SNS subscription filter policies, by assigning multiple values to an attribute name.

Your example:

```json
{
   "customer_interests": [{"exists": false}, "paintball"]
}
```

should result in filtering messages that:

- do not have the `customer_interests` message attribute
- OR have the `customer_interests` message attribute  set to `paintball`

Please note that additions or changes to a subscription filter policy require *up to 15 minutes* to fully take effect, as Amazon SNS is eventually consistent.

Changes will not always take effect immediately.